# Web font hosted on another domain

Tags: css, dns, cloud, cdn, webfonts

I would like to know if it's possible to host webfonts on another domain,
My CSS are hosted on Amazon CloudFront and my webfonts too but they don't show up, It was fine when my css were in local.

this is my style.css on CloudFront:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Aller';
    src: url('/app/files/fonts/allerdisplay-webfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('/app/files/fonts/allerdisplay-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/app/files/fonts/allerdisplay-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/app/files/fonts/allerdisplay-webfont.svg#webfontLZ8nc4vC') format('svg');
    font-weight: 900;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The stylesheet is hosted on CloudFront using a subdomain: static.mydomain.com/style.css
And the Webfont can be downloaded from : static.mydomain.com/app/files/fonts/allerdisplay-webfont.ttf

Unfortunately when the stylesheet is called from mydomain.com it doesn't load it. I was wondering if it's a limitation or something like that.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be no problem with an absolute path for the URL in the style declaration.

In your code above, you have relative path URLs.
You need an absolute path URL, like:

"http://static.mydomain.com/app/files/fonts/allerdisplay-webfont.ttf" (absolute)

-- not --

"/app/files/fonts/allerdisplay-webfont.ttf" (relative)

Theoretically, depending on the architecture of your subdomain, you might be able to rig up a way to maintain a relative URL, but this would not be worth the trouble.  Just use an absolute one and be done with it.

[previous suggestions below were posted before the relevant code was posted]
But [Google Web Fonts](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/getting_started.html) achieves all this by moving the entire style sheet to the cloud.  If you can't get it running inside the style sheet, you might try creating a separate style sheet like that instead.

Note, however, that to get true cross-browser compatibility, you need a bunch of different font file formats... this could be the problem.  [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com) has a font kit generator you may want to check out for that.